# Invoke CoMarshalInterface to marshal Workbook COM reference

Tags: excel, vba, com

I'm looking for a smart way to send "references" to various COM objects - for example, references to an Excel Workbook, or later on a Range, a Worksheet etc. - to another process via VBA. I'm currently exploring the way suggested here: [Passing a reference to a COM object accross processes via IPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379793/passing-a-reference-to-a-com-object-accross-processes-via-ipc/49394032#49394032) .

In short, I'm trying to invoke CoMarshalInterface() to marshal the Workbook reference into a stream (later on, I would send the bytes from that stream to another process that would un-marshal it again).

However, I can't seem to make it work; CoMarshalInterface() returns E_INVALIDARGS in below case. Would anybody know what's going wrong here?

```
Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As UUID) As Long

Declare Function CoMarshalInterface Lib "ole32" (_
    ByRef pStream As Variant, _
    riid As Variant, _
    pUnknown As Variant, _
    dwWestContext As Long, _
    pvDestContextPtr As Long, _
    mshflags As Long _
) As Long

Public Type UUID 'GUID
  Data1 As Long
  Data2 As Integer
  Data3 As Integer
  Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Const IID_WORKBOOK As String = "{000208DA-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

Const MSHCTX_LOCAL As Long = 0
Const MSHLFLAGS_TABLESTRONG = 1

Const S_OK = &H0
Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057

Public Sub test()
    Dim iid As UUID
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_WORKBOOK), iid)

    Dim oStream As Object
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1 ' Binary

    Dim wb As IUnknown
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim result As Long
    result = CoMarshalInterface(oStream, VarPtr(iid), ObjPtr(wb), MSHCTX_LOCAL, 0, MSHLFLAGS_TABLESTRONG)

    ' Result is E_INVALIDARG
    Debug.Print "result: 0x" & Hex(result)

    oStream.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `UUID.Data4` should probably be of size 8.

Comment: Thanks - just tried, but getting the same error there

Comment: And `Data4` probably already is of size 8.  With no `Option Base`, `Data4(7) As Byte` is the same as `Data4(1 to 7) As Byte`.  Yet, for clarity and safety, I would declare it as either `Data4(0 to 7) As Byte` or `Data4(1 to 8) As Byte`.  Sorry I couldn't help you with E_INVALIDARG.  Can you tell if `wb` is not `Nothing`, if `ObjPtr(wb)` is not 0, if `VarPtr(iid)` is not 0, etc?  Also, you should use `LongPtr` for pointers, which makes a difference in case you're running the 64-bit version of Excel.

Comment: @acelent - thanks, I think both the inputs as well as structs are fine. I've actually solved this now, instead of using an ADO Stream I am creating one via invoking CreateStreamOnHGlobal() from ole32.dll, and this works. I'd still prefer to use the ADO Stream (I have to lodge quite a few invokes in my current way), but not sure what's wrong there. My suspicion is that CoMarshalInterface() expects a pointer to the COM Interface, which I believe would be a different one than the pointer to the ADO Stream implementing IStream - but might be wrong, not a COM expert unfortunately